# How to give 2 arguments to a "Do-While"?

Tags: j

### the problem

This is a recurring difficulty I encounter when I reach for a `(u^:v^:_ y)` (Do-While) construct.

As context, it was inspired by [this code golf question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/131922/find-the-serialized-integer#131922), which asks you to build up a string from integers, starting with `0`, appending the stringified form of the next integer, until the length reaches the number given.

For example, if we stop at length 5, we build up the string `01234` (which has length 5).  The last number appended was `4`, hence we return `4` as our answer.  If we were to stop at length 12, we would produce the 12-character string `012345678910`, and hence return `10`.

### ugly solution

Here is a helper verb `len` which, given a list of integers, will return the total length of their representation as a `''`-joined string:

```
len =. +/ @: (#@":"0)
```

The following expression will then return the correct puzzle answer for input 12:

```
(>: ^: (<&12@len@:i.@>:) ^:_) 0  NB. returns 10
```

### question

The problem is that I have hard-coded my input `12` into the expression, rather than accepting it as an argument to the tacit verb.

Yet I don't see how to correct this.  The "Do" verb -- the incrementing counter -- is the one that receives the argument.  Since it always starts at 0, *it* should be hardcoded, rather than hardcoding the stopping length.  But because of the semantics of "Do-While", I don't see how I'd do that, because it accepts an argument to the main verb `u`, not the condition verb `v`.

Is there an elegant way to solve this?

Would standard recursion with `$:` and `@.` be a good strategy?

I know I could make the argument a list containing both the "stopping length" and the counter, but that will just clutter the code with bookkeeping verbs like `{.` and `{:` as I tease apart and piece together the list on each iteration.

### bonus question

In the notes for "Do-While", NuVoc warns, "Despite its name, Do-While is very rarely used in J. Almost all looping is done using the other modifiers", suggesting there might be another approach altogether.

I don't see how that's possible in this case without the unacceptable method of first guessing at an upper-bound for the answer, but if there is, I'd like to know.

Comment: You can pass the left argument to the inner verb directly. The general scheme is  `x u ^: v y ↔ x u^:(x v y) y`. Use `[` or `]` to ignore an argument if you have to.

Comment: @Eelvex, thank you

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to provide the upper-bound as the left argument. You need to adjust your "Do" and "While" verbs to use the left & right arguments appropriately but, if I understand your question correctly, the following seems to work:

```
   12 (>:@] ^: ([ > len@:i.@>:@]) ^:_) 0
10
```

If you want to "fix" the `0` starting point you could bind it as the right argument:

```
   (>:@] ^: ([ > len@:i.@>:@]) ^:_)&0 ] 12
10
```

In the interests of golfing you could incorporate the `len` verb into the current expression and shorten to this:

```
   (>:@]^:(>' '#@-.~":@i.@>:@])^:_)&0 ] 12
10
```

Comment: Definitely an improvement.  I still don't love that you have to pass 0 (the starting point is fixed).  Also, for the v verb, how does it take the right argument from the iterating value, but always use the original left argument?  is that just how it works?

Comment: Yes my understanding is that the output from `^:` becomes the right argument. Left argument is unchanged. e.g. `4 (+^:(<4)) 2` adds 4 to result each time.

Comment: @Jonah, you can form this without any left argument like `(u ^: v ^:_) 0 12` if this appeals to you more.